# Dropwizard integration test cannot find resource file

Tags: intellij-idea, dropwizard

Very new to dropwizard, I am trying to create an integration test "exactly" how they have it as an example:

```
https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/testing.html
public class LoginAcceptanceTest {

@ClassRule
public static final DropwizardAppRule<TestConfiguration> RULE =
        new DropwizardAppRule<TestConfiguration>(MyApp.class, ResourceHelpers.resourceFilePath("dev-config.yml"));

@Test
public void loginHandlerRedirectsAfterPost() {
    //Client client = new JerseyClientBuilder(RULE.getEnvironment()).build("test client");


}
}
```

so far having 2 issues: first of all when I run the test from intellij it fails with following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: resource dev-config.yml not found.
```

full stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.java:43)
at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:140)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Field.java:1057)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:1038)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:379)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkField.get(FrameworkField.java:73)
at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.getAnnotatedFieldValues(TestClass.java:230)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.classRules(ParentRunner.java:255)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.withClassRules(ParentRunner.java:244)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.classBlock(ParentRunner.java:194)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:362)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: resource dev-config.yml not found.
at io.dropwizard.testing.ResourceHelpers.resourceFilePath(ResourceHelpers.java:23)
at com.amplify.ckla.resources.TeacherConfigResourceIntegrationTest.<clinit>(TeacherConfigResourceIntegrationTest.java:12)
... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: resource dev-config.yml not found.
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:145)
at com.google.common.io.Resources.getResource(Resources.java:197)
at io.dropwizard.testing.ResourceHelpers.resourceFilePath(ResourceHelpers.java:21)
... 22 more
```

the dev-config.yml is definitely there:

```
ls -a 
.               .idea               build.sh            pom.xml
..              CKLA.iml            dev-config.yml          src
.git                README.md                       target
.gitignore          develop.sh
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the run directory of the program to be the root of the project (the one with the output of the `ls -a` command). Most likely currently you are running it from `./target` directory.

Or if you want/need to run from `.target` change the command line options to refer the configuration file to: `../dev-config.yml`

**Edit:**
As @nightograph commented the exact thing to do in *IntelliJ* is to right click on the project folder and mark directory as `"Resources Root"`

Comment: thanks! specifically for IntelliJ, I had to right click on the project folder and mark directory as "Resources Root"

Comment: I generally use Eclipse and I wasn't sure how the things looks in IntelliJ. I'll add the your comment in the answer.

Comment: I put a copy of the YML to be used for testing in the test/resources folder instead