# How do I specify the Dropwizard config file in Intellij for unit tests?

Tags: intellij-idea, junit, dropwizard

I'm developing an application in Dropwizard 0.9, using IntelliJ Idea as my IDE. I have a run configuration configured, and it passes the command line arguments "server ./path/to/config.yml" to specify the configuration file to run with.

When I try to run my unit tests, however, I cannot determine how to pass this config file path to the server. The Run/Debug Configuration dialog has a "Program Arguments" field, but it is permanently disabled (and the edit button adjacent to it does nothing).

How can I enable program arguments, or, alternatively, is there another way to specify the config file for tests?

Comment: DW offers a way of doing that which is documented here: http://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.2/docs/manual/testing.html#integration-testing. If you show some code and your approach i might be able to help more, however without seeing your setup I would be blindly guessing

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087777/dropwizard-integration-test-cannot-find-resource-file/29096868

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your config.yml is in the project's root folder, just set *server config.yml* in the IDE. Take a look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=doz1HzxLUkU).

If you would like to access the config.yml from the project's root folder, just pass the name of the file to the rule.

```
@ClassRule
public static final DropwizardAppRule<DWGettingStartedConfiguration> RULE
        = new DropwizardAppRule<>(DWGettingStartedApplication.class,
                "config.yml");
```

Also, it is possible to store the configuration file for integration tests in the src/test/resources folder. In this case, the file can be accessed using the following code:

```
/**
 * A path to test configuration file.
 */
private static final String CONFIG_PATH
        = ResourceHelpers.resourceFilePath("test-config.yml");
/**
 * Start the application before all test methods.
 */
@ClassRule
public static final DropwizardAppRule<DropBookmarksConfiguration> RULE
        = new DropwizardAppRule<>(
                DropBookmarksApplication.class,
                CONFIG_PATH);
```

In addition, please take a look at my example projects [here](https://bitbucket.org/dnoranovich/dropwizard-getting-started), [here](https://bitbucket.org/dnoranovich/dropbookmarks) and [here](https://github.com/javaeeeee/DropBookmarks).